# when changing singleton fragment, recyclerview has this status?

Tags: android

I'm using singleton fragment. I thought when I call this singleton fragment, the lifecycle methods `onCreateView` and `onActivityCreated` will be called only once. But they aren't even though the fragment is singleton, `onCreateView` and `onActivityCreated` are called when I call fragment. But I found something strange. That is, the `RecyclerView` is holding it's position. If I move A frag(using `RecyclerView`, position at 20) to B frag and redirect to A frag, the A fragment position is 20. Although `onCreateView` and `onActivityCreated` are called again, Why the A fragment position is saved?

ps: I know kotlin support singleton class "Objcet". But I'm more comfortable using singleton constructor than object class.

*MainActivity*

```
    navigation_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        when(it.itemId){
            R.id.scheduleFragment->{
                changeFragment(scheduleFragment)
            }
            R.id.noticeFragment->{
                changeFragment(NoticeFragment())
            }

        }

        true
    }

}
```

*fragment*

```
 companion object {
     var scheduleFragment: ScheduleFragment? = null
  }

fun getInstance(context: Context): ScheduleFragment {
    if (scheduleFragment == null) {
        scheduleFragment = ScheduleFragment()

    }
    return scheduleFragment!!
}
```

Comment: You can't make a Fragment a singleton. You're going about this entire thing wrong. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's behaving exactly as expected. The recycler-view's view, position all are members to the fragment instance. So the values remain same as it has only single instance. But the life cycle methods have nothing to do with the fact that the fragment class is singleton. They get called when the specific event happens. For example, when the activity is created then the onActivityCreated method get called by the system and this method calling has nothing to do about the fragment instance creation. Because the fragment instance creation happens earlier when you make an instance of fragment. Now after the use either you want to keep the instance or destroy it, it's your choice. Hope this will clear your confusion. Let me know if you don't understand anything.